# Adding a new servlet to Vaadin Flow/Spring project

Tags: java, spring, servlets, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I would like to add a separate HTTPServlet to a vaadin/Spring boot project but with no success. I don't want to customize the vaadin servlet with specific booting behaviour, but to have a separate component serving as a servlet in the same project. I tried do add/register it with mapping annotations, also as a Spring Bean but the new servlet URL is not mapped to the class and vaadin flow keeps falling on the root route initially set. Any help to point me in the right direction is very appreciated.

Comment: Might help if you added specifics about what you tried and how they failed.

Comment: Also what `urlMapping` are you using for the vaadin servlet.

Comment: Documentation about setting url mapping of Vaadin servlet is here https://vaadin.com/docs/v20/flow/integrations/spring/configuration#using-spring-boot-properties If you add separate HTTPservlet in your project, you need to deploy that and Vaadin under different url mapping / deployment context.

Comment: Dear Tatu Lund, thanks for the link and for the information. It solved my issue. The problem was that I did not add/register the Sevlet Bean within the main spring boot application but tried to add the notation into a separate HTTPServlet class. Thank you again for the prompt help.

Comment: Gianfranco, can you formulate that as answer to this question, so that this is not left hanging un-answered.